# Custom Short Code to Loop Through Custom Content Types

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, shortcode

I have a website that use the custom-content-shortcode plugin for Wordpress. It has some incompatibility and has brought down our site a couple of times. I am doing the follow:

```html
[loop type="th_sermons" taxonomy="th_sermons_speaker" value="speaker-slug" count="5"]
    <li>
        <a href="[field url]">
            <span class="placeholder">[field thumbnail]</span>
            <p>
                <h5 class="rlcf-custom-sermon-list-title">[field title]</h5>
                <span class="rlcf-custom-sermon-list-date">[field date]</span>
            </p>
        </a>
    </li>
    [if empty]
        There are no sermons for this category.
    [else]
        <li>
            <a href="/speakers/speaker-slug/">More Messages By Speaker Name</a>
        </li>
    [/if]
[/loop]
```

It works great when it works, but bringing the site down is not a good outcome. I think it would be a easy to write a custom short code that would accomplish this. Something like this.

```html
[rlcf_sermons speaker="speaker-slug" count="optional_or_number"]
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should point you in the right direction to add a custom shortcode in your theme `functions.php` file:

```
add_shortcode( 'rlcf_sermons', function( $atts ){

    // set default attributes
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'speaker' => '',
        'count'   => -1
    ), $atts ) );

    // query
    $sermons = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => 'th_sermons',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'th_sermons_speaker',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $speaker
            )
        ),
        'posts_per_page' => $count
    ));

    // output
    if($sermons->have_posts()):

        while ( $sermons->have_posts() ) :
            $sermons->the_post();
            // here goes all the code you want for each LI tag
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();

    else: echo 'There are no sermons for this category.';

    endif;

} );
```

Reference: [add_shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode) and [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query).

Comment: Thank you so much. The "query" section of the code is crashing the site. What might be going on?

Comment: There was a typo, a missing comma before `'posts_per_page'`. However, you should activate the [debug](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) to be able to find in case these errors.

Comment: Thanks. I found it right after I posted this. I really appreciate your help!